# Docker compose override host variable

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, overriding

My docker setup running in strange situation

Dir Structure

```
SweetVPN/
  .env
  docker-compose.yml
```

**.env**

```
USER=myuser
PASS=mypass
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
environment:
   - USER=${USER}
   - PASS=${PASS}
```

When I run container, it says username & password is incorrect, obviously, username or password is wrong.

When I check

```
❯ docker exec SweetVPN env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=b6dc9052d7d9
USER=rahul
PASS=mypass
```

**Issue :**

```
user=rahul
```

Is my host user, which is taking by default from docker, Is there any way to override host variable in docker-compose?

I tried in host `unset $USER`, but it didn't succeed.

Comment: `$USER` is a special environment variable and I wouldn't use it for application-level configuration.  It'd be like using `$PATH` to set part of the URL; conventionally it means something totally different.

Answer (score 0):

your user `rahul` / `mypass` should be created in Dockerfile used by your docker compose, and then, replace:

```
environment:
   - USER=${USER}
   - PASS=${PASS}
```

by

```
user: <your_USER>
```

For more information, [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir)